# Laptop DELL Inspiron 14z 5423 - OS freeze issue

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, freeze, dell-inspiron

I purchased a DELL Laptop model Inspiron 14z 5423

And i'm presenting an issue with the Windows 7 installation it comes with.

It keeps freezing, i mean if i Power on the device, it loads just fine, then comes Windows 7 login screen, after that i login normally, then after 5 to 10 minutes independently of what i'm doing it just freezes the screen, and i can't make it work again, only option is to reboot the machine, and after that, the same vicious circle.

What could be the issue in these circumstances?

Some BIOS not set up correctly?

Video drivers?

Could someone give some advice to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you get to safe mode?

Comment: I'm going to try it tomorrow, because i have it at the office, then i'll post any update regarding it

Comment: check all 3 steps from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

Comment: I installed Dell's PC Checkup software and it solved the problem, it was some corrupt installation and lack of drivers issues, thank you for your interest!